# Are function aliases bad?

Tags: function, refactoring, alias

Did you ever write a function Foo, use it in your program, then eventually decided to refactor your code and rewrite another function Bar, that is better than Foo, and decided "Oh well, we'll use Bar instead of Foo from now on". But instead of just deleting Foo and replacing every occurence of Foo in the code, you decided to declare Foo as an alias of function Bar ?

Some of you may say : why didn't you just rewrite function Foo and keep its name as Foo, so you don't have to replace every occurence of Foo with Bar ? well, because of the refactoring, Foo isn't an appropriate name anymore, because it does not reflect what the function does, so I decided to not keep its name.

Is this some kind of retrocompatibility ?

EDIT : Suppose

1. Foo was written by one of you coworkers
2. said coworkers are used to Foo
3. you're the moron in the story who thinks is smarter than the others and wrote Bar

Comment: That sort of *lazy* alias is bad, yes. Use a real refactoring tool. That isn't to say aliases are bad. As far as "compatibility" -- it depends on who the consumers are and if it's exposed, etc. But generally this compatibility would be handled by a proxy or other deprecation route and *not* an alias.

Comment: It depends on if Foo is a *misleading* name for Bar.  Your technique is a common one for preserving backward compatibility.  In Java you can mark Foo as `@Deprecated` with a comment saying that Bar is a better choice going forward, and the compiler will mark occurrences of Foo with a warning

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it was that easy in Java. Great comment, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Foo was written by one of you coworkers
said coworkers are used to Foo
you're the moron in the story who thinks is smarter than the others and wrote Bar
```

Ask your coworkers and explain why you want to rename it.  Chances are they won't care unless they really believe the original name is better.  If the method is in a public-facing API or used by hundreds of developers then deprecate it.  Otherwise, just rename it everywhere using a refactoring tool.

You can also alias it if you are trying to make your code read like a DSL and have want two ways to say the same thing (like in Ruby).